# Calculating the distance between two planes in rviz

Tags: rviz, pcl, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,
I am working on a project to calculate the distance between the vehicle's base and the ground. I am working on Ubuntu 11.10 with ROS-electric(with PCL) and using Asus xtion pro live RGB-D sensor. I have successfully filtered two planes. Necessary for the foot placement of a humanoid robot. Here is the video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6x4PLk89mig .  Is there an easy way to calculate the distance between these two planes rather than me plugging in formula(or developing a ROS node) to calculate the distance between the planes.

thanks,
karthik.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/51565/calculating-the-distance-between-two-planes-in-rviz/) by [metal](https://answers.ros.org/users/1575/metal/) on ROS Answers with karma: 174 on 2013-01-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You've already written a ROS node in C++ to find the two planes, right? You can do the calculation in that same node using C++.

What specifically do you want to calculate? The vertical distance between planes? Or the distance between the closest two points on the planes? Or something else? Either of these could be calculated using PCL/Eigen

Also, electric is a pretty old version of ROS, you may want to upgrade to fuerte or groovy if you can :-)

---

Originally posted by [jbinney](https://answers.ros.org/users/3292/jbinney/) with karma: 606 on 2013-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0